# Breakpoint setted in VSC changes after starting chrome debug

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, remote-debugging

I want to debug my reactjs app in chrome with visual studio code via remote debugging. When I try to set a breakpoint in the source code and than start the remote debug session, the breakpoint is changing the line.
How could that be?

[image: setted breakpoint changes after start]